# 'Initializing': Cannot convert from 'const wchar_t[35]' to 'LPWSTR'

Tags: c++, lpwstr

i am currently learning C++ and want to change my desktop wallpaper. However i am getting this error above.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std; 

int main() {

LPWSTR test = L"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\minion.png";

int result = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, 
test, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE);


}
```

A value of type "Const wchar_t*" cannot be used to initialize an entity of type LPWSTR

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Project > Properties > C/C++ > Language, "Conformance mode" = No.

Comment: @HansPassant , thank you. I used a flag that didn't work ...  like this `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= /permissive-`  not even sure possible outside VS2017.. any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LPWSTR` is an alias for `wchar_t*`, ie a pointer to a non-const character.

A string literal is a const array of characters, in your case a `const wchar_t[35]`. It decays into a pointer to a const character, pointing at the 1st character in the literal.

You can't assign a pointer-to-const to a pointer-to-non-const. That would allow writing access to read-only memory.

Use `LPCWSTR` instead, which is an alias for `const wchar_t*`.

```
LPCWSTR test = L"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\minion.png";
```

Comment: while this is quite evident .. I am suspicious when confronted with MSDN examples that promote (well looks like) using LPWSTR    .. for instance , this example : [Querying for Event Information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/eventlog/querying-for-event-source-messages)

Comment: Most examples were written for C, or early C++ before C++11 started enforcing that non-const pointers could no longer point at string literals.

Comment: hmmm , makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: This is finally starting to make sense for me, but how would I go about with the following usage given that the FormatMessage requires a LPWSTR: `FormatMessage(..., msg, 0, null); if(msg == null){msg = "L"Error: '" + to_wstring(GetLastError()) " + FormatMessage returned null.";`

Comment: @Reahreic That is not the correct way to check for failure. That code only makes sense if you use `FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER`, in which case you need to pass a `wchar_t**` casted to `wchar_t*`. Third, you can't store a pointer to a temp string. Change `msg` into `wstring` and use `LPWSTR` for the allocation, eg: `wstring msg; LPWSTR buf = nullptr; if (FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER, reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&buf), 0, nullptr)) { msg = buf; LocalFree(buf); } else { msg = L"Error: '" + to_wstring(GetLastError()) + L"' FormatMessage failed."; }`

Answer (score 4):

The MSVC compiler is getting less and less permissive. On the whole that's a good thing.

`L"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\minion.png"` is a literal of type `const wchar_t[34]` (the extra element is for the string terminator). That *decays* to a `const wchar_t*` pointer in certain circumstances.

`LPWSTR` is not a `const` pointer type so compilation will fail on a standard C++ compiler.

The solution is to use the `const` pointer type `LPCWSTR`.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to resolve this compilation error is to set Conformance Mode to Default in the project Properties -> C/C++ -> Language. At least it worked in my VS2019 project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I'm sure this can be compiled.

```
LPCWSTR dd = L"C:\\Users\\user\\Pictures\\minion.png";
si.lpDesktop = reinterpret_cast<LPWSTR>(&dd);
```

Comment: That's a very odd way of casting a const to a non-const and, like is often the case when using `reinterpret_cast` unnecessarily, can cause a crash later on. In this case you're telling the compiler that your new pointer points to modifiable data but it doesn't. I also can't see how this relates to the actual question.

Comment: Please negative my post, I also found this has problem :)